# Excel: Use value of cell instead of formula in another formula

Tags: excel

I am getting incorrect results in excel when cross-referencing formulas.

I firstly created a cell `D4 = AVERAGE(D1:D3)` formatted in a percent `2.70%`.

Now I am trying to use this percent in `D4` to multiply a number in cell `A1`, `176522.5` which should give me the answer `4766.1075` however Excel is returning the value `4758.19902` which is incorrect.

I think the problem is coming from Excel using the `AVERAGE(D1:D3` instead of the actual value in the cell.

Apologies is this may seem trivial.

How can I force Excel to use the actual value and not the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ROUND(your formula , 2)
```

2 represents the number or decimal points you want to use.  a negative number will round to the left of the decimal.  set 2 to be a number that matches however many decimal points you are using.  in the case of a percentage, you may need to add 2 to the number of decimal places.